# Turn off pasting for QTextEdit object using PySide6

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I'm trying to turn off pasting for a `QtWidgets.QtextEdit` object (PySide6), but am confused about whether it's off by default across platforms. E.g., I intuitively thought the following would work:

```
class MyEditor(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def _setup_interface(self):
        self.canPaste(False)
```

but this results in an error since `QtWidgets.QTextEdit.canPaste` doesn't take an argument. Is there a way to explicitly turn off pasting, or do I need to trust it will be off by default?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to *completely* disable pasting? For a text edit, basic clipboard functionalities are considered normal, especially for *internal* usage: for instance, if the user wants to select a section of text and copy or move it in another position using the mouse or the keyboard. Completely disabling pasting will result in an unexpected (and annoying) behavior. Maybe what you actually want is to prevent pasting from *external* sources, or avoid pasting of specific types of contents (images, paths, etc)?

Comment: @musicamante in this particular situation, I do want to completely disable pasting from external sources and internal sources. I'd try to implement a specific check for special pastes in the cases you're describing, and I do agree in the vast majority of cases disabling pastes would not be a great design call :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names of functions that apply parameters or properties normally start with a `set`.
[`canPaste()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#canPaste) just tells if the content of the clipboard can be used to paste in the text edit.

The solution is to override [`insertFromMimeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData), which is called every time there is an attempt to *paste* content, and just do nothing:

```
class NoPasteTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def insertFromMimeData(self, source):
        pass
```

Note that the context menu will still show the "Paste" action, so you should probably disable that, which can be achieved by overriding [`canInsertFromMimeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#canInsertFromMimeData) and always returning False:

```
    def canInsertFromMimeData(self, source):
        return False
```

Be aware, though, that this will completely compromise the default behavior of internal editing through clipboard, including dragging a text selection to move it to another position.

A possible alternative is to override [`createMimeDataFromSelection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#createMimeDataFromSelection), get the QMimeData of the default implementation and add a custom format, in this way we can check in `insertFromMimeData()` and `canInsertFromMimeData()` whether the "pasted" data is generated internally or not and eventually accept or ignore it.

```
class NoPasteTextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def canInsertFromMimeData(self, source):
        return source.hasFormat('InternalClipboard')

    def insertFromMimeData(self, source):
        if source.hasFormat('InternalClipboard'):
            super().insertFromMimeData(source)

    def createMimeDataFromSelection(self):
        # the mime object returned from the default implementation does
        # not allow to set further arbitrary data, so we just create a
        # standard QMimeData and fill it with the existing data
        mime = QtCore.QMimeData()
        src = super().createMimeDataFromSelection()
        for fmt in src.formats():
            mime.setData(fmt, src.data(fmt))
        mime.setData('InternalClipboard', QtCore.QByteArray())
        return mime
```